# Managing composable functions with Jetpack Compose Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have few `@Composable` functions that contains UI. I've also set up `BottomNavigation` with `Scaffold`, which works just fine. Now the problem is, I can't figure out how would I navigate to a different screen/composable in fullscreen(with full width and height). Look at below code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = { TopBar() },
        floatingActionButton = {
            if(currentRoute(navController) != "more")
                FAB()
        },
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController) },
        content = { innerPadding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                NavigateScreens(navController = navController)
            }
        },
    )
}
```

This code works fine but as you can see my `NavigateScreens` is in the `Scaffold`'s content so everything renders between `TopBar` and `BottomNavigation`. How would I structure this so I can also open composable in fullscreen?

Comment: Please refer the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable). There are examples explaining how to do this. And a [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#0) as well.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into the compose samples on GitHub. Most of the projects have navigation so it can be useful.

You need to create a NavHost (or AnimatedNavHost) and a 'composable(destination)' for each screen.

The code below is a simplified AnimatedNavHost from one of my projects to illustrate how you should do it:

```
fun MainActivity.NavGraph(startDestination: String = "Home") {

AnimatedNavHost(
    navController = navController!!,
    startDestination = startDestination,
    enterTransition = { _, _ ->
        expandIn()
    },
    popEnterTransition = { _, _ ->
        expandIn()
    },
    exitTransition = { _, _ ->
        shrinkOut()
    },
    popExitTransition = { _, _ ->
        shrinkOut()
    },
) {

    // Static destinatin
    composable("Home") { 

        val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel(it)

        HomeScreen(
            homeViewModel = homeViewModel,
            navController = navController!!
        )

    }

    // Dynamic destination
    composable(
        route = "Category" + "/{categoryName}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("categoryName") {
            type = NavType.StringType
        })
    ) {

        val categoryViewModel: CategoryViewModel = hiltViewModel(it)

        val categoryName =
            it.arguments?.getString("categoryName") ?: ""

        CategoryScreen(
            categoryViewModel = categoryViewModel,
            navController = navController!!,
            categoryName = categoryName
        )

    }

}
```

}